# Job application form requires to enter name of the city and state in US

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

even for positions that offer visa sponshorship, i.e. candidates aren't supposed to be in the US currently. And I couldn't find any country selection field.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean; it's not clear from the question? There's no requirement to enter a US address in SO jobs when applying to a job.

Comment: @ Dean Ward, hm. Can it be different depending on the offer's settings?

Comment: Can you post the job link here? We have two types of application process; one using SO jobs and one that allows the employer to provide a link to their own application system. Suspect you're applying to a job that uses the latter!

Comment: @ Dean Ward, http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/104073/server-software-engineer-zazzle?searchTerm=c%23%20and%20not%20company%3Acrossover&offset=6&offersvisasponsorship=True&rs=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This employer uses an external application process that is out of our control. I'll get our support team to reach out to the customer and let them know about this issue.

Thanks for the report!